# Calling Msg.sender Natively

Tags: delegatecall

Caller -> Contract B -> Contract A

Contract A has a msg.sender variable.

I want to use the Caller as Msg.Sender for Contract A through Contract B.

How is this done?

Comment: The question is unclear. Please consider adding the relevant part of your code.

Comment: _allowed[msg.sender][spender] that's what I have under the main contract. I want to be able to have msg.sender be passed as the calling contract.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two common variables for finding out senders. There´s `msg.sender` which gives address of the one who sent/relayed the current transaction call - so the previous contract or EOA (Externally Owned Account) in the chain of contract calls. Then there´s `tx.origin` which is the original issuers of the transaction - always an EOA, never a contract as a contract can't issue a new transaction. Typically `tx.origin` is very seldom needed and shouldn't be used. In your case `tx.origin` gives what you want but I suggest to rethink your design so you wouldn't need that.

Comment: I am unable to change the already uploaded contract's msg.sender variable. I can only write the calling contract differently.

Comment: You can't change the value of `msg.sender` explicitly - that comes from the environment.